# How do I Reference Service's Property from another Kubernetes Entity?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any option to reference service's property from another entity, Like Config Map or Deployment? To be more specific I want to put service's name in ConfigMap, not by myself, but rather to link it programmatically.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 
kind: ConfigMap 
metadata:
  name: config-map 
  namespace: ConfigMap-Namespace 

Data:
  ServiceName: <referenced-service-name> 

--- 

apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata:
 name: service-name           /// that name I want to put in ConfigMap.
 namespace: ConfigMap-Namespace 
spec:
   ....
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain `kubectl`, there is no way to dynamically fill in content like this.  There are very limited exceptions around injecting values into environment variables in Pods (and PodSpecs inside other objects) but a ConfigMap must contain fixed content.

In this example, the Service object name is fixed, and I'd just embed the same fixed string into the ConfigMap.

If you were using a templating engine like [Helm](https://helm.sh) then you could call the same template code to render the Service name in both places.  For example:

```yaml
{{- define "service.name" -}}
{{ .Release.Name }}-service
{{- end -}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: {{ include "service.name" . }}
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: { ... }
data:
  serviceName: {{ include "service.name" . }}
```